# Преобразование массив в дерево js

Tags: javascript, массивы, дерево

Есть массив данных, который необходимо преобразовать в дерево:

```
const array = [{
  id: 5,
  name: 'vueJS',
  parentId: 3
}, {
  id: 6,
  name: 'reactJS',
  parentId: 3
}, {
  id: 3,
  name: 'js',
  parentId: 1
}, {
  id: 1,
  name: 'dev',
  parentId: null
}, {
  id: 4,
  name: 'photoshop',
  parentId: 2
}, {
  id: 2,
  name: 'UX',
  parentId: null
}];
```

Сейчас это работает с помощью такой функции:

```
function arrayToTree(array, parent) {
  var unflattenArray = [];
  array.forEach(function(item) {
    if(item.parentId === parent) {
      var children = arrayToTree(array, item.id);
      if(children.length) {
        item.children = children
      }
      unflattenArray.push(item)
    }
  });
  return unflattenArray;
}
console.log(arrayToTree(array, null));
```

Есть две проблемы с этой функцией:
 1. Значение "parentId" должен быть массивом id, например - parentId: [2,
    3]
 2. Как передавать в функцию только один аргумент - array?

https://codepen.io/pershay/pen/PgVJOO?editors=0010

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const

tree = array => array
  .reduce ((a, c) => {
    c.children = array.filter (i => i.parentId == c.id)
    a.push (c)
    return a
  }, [])
  .filter (i => i.parentId == null)

console.log (tree ([
  {id: 5, name: 'vueJS', parentId: 3},
  {id: 6, name: 'reactJS', parentId: 3},
  {id: 3, name: 'js', parentId: 1},
  {id: 1, name: 'dev', parentId: null},
  {id: 4, name: 'photoshop', parentId: 2},
  {id: 2, name: 'UX', parentId: null}
]))
```

Comment: а комментария к коду не будет ?

Answer (score 1):

Я так понимаю заботиться о сохранности оригинального массива не требуется, вследствие чего предлагаю вариант по проще чем со сверткой:

```js
let makeTree = array => array.filter(item => {
  // создаем у каждого элемента массив из ссылок на его потомков
  item.children = array.filter(i => i.parentId === item.id);
  // оставляем в фильтруемом массиве только элементы верхнего уровня
  return item.parentId == null;
});

let array = [
  {id: 5, name: 'vueJS', parentId: 3},
  {id: 6, name: 'reactJS', parentId: 3},
  {id: 3, name: 'js', parentId: 1},
  {id: 1, name: 'dev', parentId: null},
  {id: 4, name: 'photoshop', parentId: 2},
  {id: 2, name: 'UX', parentId: null}
];

console.log (makeTree(array));
```

Comment: Необычное решение!