# Структурирование данных в Js. Как сделать дерево из массива?

Tags: javascript, структуры-данных

Первый раз сталкиваюсь со структурированием и я в ступоре.
Есть массив с объектами которые имеют только `parent: id`
Cildrens(потомки) неизвестно
Так же известен корневой элемент.
Т.е. примерно так:

```
[

{Id: 14, parent: 98, name: 'a'}
{Id: 76, parent: 98, name: 'd'}
{Id: 28, parent: 0, _root: true, name: 'root' }
{Id: 98, parent: 28, name: 'b'}
{Id: 13, parent: 56, name: 'f'}
{Id: 19, parent: 56, name: 'c'}
{Id: 56, parent: 28, name: 'h'}
{Id: 87, parent: 19, name: 'g'}

]
```

Как каждому объекту добавить свойство, которое будет массивом и содержать Id всех прямых потомков?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/997997/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D0%B8%D0%B7-javascript-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/975430/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2-%D0%B2-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE-js